# Custom Authentication Provider is not getting called Spring Security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to implement a custom AuthenticationProvider to authenticate calls to all my protected URLs. I have implemented all the methods and believe that my xml configuration is correct, but calls to protected URLs always go to the entry-point-ref class (where I throw a 401 error). This is skipping my authentication provider (I have log statements inside my authenticate method and know it is not getting called). From other posts I have learned that the supports method could be the culprit, but I have set it to always return true so this should not be my issue.

Code for my security-context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:http 
            use-expressions="true"
            auto-config="false"
            create-session="stateless"
            entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
            authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/User/sign_up/*" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/User/authenticate/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </security:http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="pathto:CustomAuthenticationProvider" />

    <beans:bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="pathto:UnauthorizedEntryPoint" /
```

Code for web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

UnauthorizedEntryPoint:

```
public class UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("in unauth");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failure: UnauthorizedEntryPoint Token invalid");
    }

}
```

AuthenticationProvider: (Currently not doing any authenticating here)

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("in authenticate");
        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();
        List<GrantedAuthority> AUTHORITIES = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        System.out.println("username: "+username+". password: "+ password);
        if (true) { //checkPassword(password, user.getPasswords())) {
            AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getName(), auth.getCredentials(), AUTHORITIES);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }
```

Update:
I am testing this using the Advanced Rest Client using parameters j_username and j_password. Is that correct or is that the problem?

Do you have any insight into what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up going a different way and setting up a custom filter to call it similar to what was done [here](http://www.networkedassets.com/en/configuring-spring-security-for-a-restful-web-services/).

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Can you provide some details how you resolved it? The link you provided is not working any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no web authentication mechanism configured, hence there is nothing to invoke the authentication manager. As a result, the request always hits your authentication entry point (which is invoked for unauthenticated users) and you get the error you observe. Typically the authentication entry point will do something like redirect to a login form, or send a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

You need to configure something like form or basic authentication (see either the manual or the samples that come with the project). Note that you have also configured the application to be stateless, so each request needs to be authenticated.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's kinda what I did with my custom filter. The stateless part is desired as I am implementing a REST service.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove `authentication-manager-ref` under `security:http` ? You have already declared `authentication-manager` tag.

```
<security:http 
        use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="false"
        create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/User/sign_up/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/User/authenticate/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</security:http>
```

Besides; not a part of your problem, but just recommendation:

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

Comment: I removed the authentication-manager-ref and tried it again (it is still not working). The reason I just had the supports method returning true was to try and get it called. After I get that to happen, I will more tightly cast it. Am I testing it correctly by passing in j_username and j_password?

Comment: As a workaround, you can test your config with `<user-service>` instead of custom application provider.

Comment: That's not really what I want to implement since I don't want to have to provide all the information for a UserDetails implementation. Do I need to implement a filter? I just don't understand why it wouldn't be getting called with the current configuration

Comment: I tried to implement this workaround, however, I still am always being sent to the UnauthorizedAccessPoint. This makes me believe it is somehow in how I configured this. Should I not be using an entry-point-ref?